# Haskell newtype with parentheses

Tags: haskell, newtype

I'm trying to understand the explaination in [Monads made difficult](http://www.stephendiehl.com/posts/monads.html) and I have a hard time figuring out the following newtype definition:

```
newtype (FComp g f) x = FComp { unCompose :: g (f x) }

instance (Functor b c f, Functor a b g) => Functor a c (FComp g f) where
  fmap f (FComp xs) = FComp $ fmap (fmap f) xs
```

I have nowhere seen an explaination of what newtype means with an expression in parentheses in place of the type declaration. I therefore cannot figure out what the definition of the fmap function means. I also don't understand why the unCompose field accessor is defined but never used. I feel like I am missing some basic semantics of newtype.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could write this:

```
newtype (FComp g f) x = FComp { unCompose :: g (f x) }
```

like so:

```
newtype FComp g f x = FComp (g (f x))
unCompose (FComp it) = it
```

This is so because type application has the same syntactic properties as ordinary applications, i.e.:

```
a b c  = (a b) c
```

holds for values a,b,c and for types a,b,c.

Answer (score 16):

A little test:

```
newtype (FComp g f) x = FComp { unCompose :: g (f x) }
newtype FComp2 g f x = FComp2 { unCompose2 :: g (f x) }

*Main> :i FComp
newtype FComp g f x = FComp {unCompose :: g (f x)}
        -- Defined at Test.hs:34:10
*Main> :i FComp2
newtype FComp2 g f x = FComp2 {unCompose2 :: g (f x)}
    -- Defined at Test.hs:35:9
```

So the parentheses really don't change anything. It's just the same as without them.

As for the `uncompose`, it's just a name to unwrap the `newtype` without making the data constructor explicit. In the snippet you posted they use pattern matching, but one wouldn't want to export the implementation details, so `unCompose` is provided to use the contents of `FComp`. This is just the same as in `data` definitions, only that `newtype` wants exactly one field instead of *0..n*.

Comment: One probably *would* want to export the implementation details, at least inasmuch as there's only one thing they could be. It's just sometimes more convenient to use an unpacking function than pattern matching.